# Stored procedure column causing error in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, datareader

Can anyone someone please help me identify which part of this stored procedure is causing an error in Entity Framework not to recognize the column named `cellNumber`? When I try to run my solution I get an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework will not recognize a column in my stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693592/entity-framework-will-not-recognize-a-column-in-my-stored-procedure)

Comment: @zidane: Your SQL Statement only returns the some columns not the full entity.

Comment: db.Database.SqlQuery<?> what are you using in place of ? mark in your C# code?

Comment: try adding in every sql statement ,*, then it will return all columns, and your entity will match, if you dont want to return all columns try mathcing columns used in entity and columns selecting in your sql select statement